GoogleAppSheet　の項目でタイプはnumber　必須項目にして０を入力したら必須項目エラーがでる。０を入力して保存する方法を教えてほしいです。
例えば預金管理で　預金残高は必須項目　０円になったら０を入力したらエラーで保存できないといったパターンです。
だからといってテキストに項目を変更するのは違うと思いますし。。。。お助けください。
